# Function to bring an element to front in phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I want to bring  an  **ArcadeSprite** element in front of all other elements.
Is there any function in phaser 3 to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArcadeSprite`s have the [`Depth`](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/6ab124c591aea172c23ff5b2f5c364ce324b73e7/src/gameobjects/components/Depth.js) component that you can use to control which elements are displayed on top of others (think of it as a z-index).

You can do something like `myArcadeSprite.depth = SOME_NUMBER_HERE`.

I want to say there are also some `bringToFront` type of methods floating around somewhere in Phaser, but I can't seem to find them.